# EC2 GRPC install hangs after 12 hours still no install

Tags: amazon-ec2, grpc

I'm pretty sure it's because I am using `t2.nano` and not something a little more beefy.

But I have used laravel forge to provision an ec2 server, I can't deploy my application however because I need to install `GRPC`.

I have followed these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc#using-pecl

And when I run: `sudo pecl install grpc` it runs for around 10 mins and then just gets stuck.

Seems to be running the same thing over and over again, can't quite workout the full stack trace or more importantly where it begins, but I'll post below.

```
DGRPC_POSIX_FORK_ALLOW_PTHREAD_ATFORK=1 -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_NAME_SUFFIX=\"PHP\" -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_VERSION_SUFFIX=\"1.41.0\" -c /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/channel_connectivity.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/.libs/channel_connectivity.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootRBppUP/grpc-1.41.0/libtool --mode=compile g++ -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootRBppUP/grpc-1.41.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootRBppUP/grpc-1.41.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/upb-generated -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/php/ext/grpc -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/abseil-cpp -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/address_sorting/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/re2 -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/upb -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/xxhash  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g -O2   -fvisibility=hidden     -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM -D_GNU_SOUR
CE -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN     -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 -DNOMINMAX -DGRPC_ARES=0     -DGRPC_POSIX_FORK_ALLOW_PTHREAD_ATFORK=1     -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_NAME_SUFFIX='"PHP"'     -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_VERSION_SUFFIX='"1.41.0"' -c /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc -o src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.lo
libtool: compile:  g++ -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootRBppUP/grpc-1.41.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootRBppUP/grpc-1.41.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/upb-generated -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/php/ext/grpc -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/abseil-cpp -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/address_sorting/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/re2 -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/upb -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/xxhash -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM -D_GNU_SOURCE -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 -DNOMINMAX -DGRPC_ARES=0 -
DGRPC_POSIX_FORK_ALLOW_PTHREAD_ATFORK=1 -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_NAME_SUFFIX=\"PHP\" -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_VERSION_SUFFIX=\"1.41.0\" -c /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/.libs/client_channel.o
```

If there are any logs I can grab please drop the command in to tail or cat and I'll attach them to the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to a bigger tier than the t2.nano and it should work. I think it's because of the RAM limit. I had the same issue with some instances in Digital Ocean.

Comment: This did end up being the solution I used so I'll give you the up vote, would be great if there was a solution to be able to still use t2.nano though :(